# Create a pivot table where the value is held flat until a certain date

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I want to create a pivot table with months as the columns and items as rows. Currently the data is in a table that looks like this:

| Item | Balance | Maturity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | 1/31/23 |
| B | 150 | 2/28/23 |
| C | 200 | 3/31/23 |

But I want the data to look like this:

|  | 1/31/23 | 2/28/23 | 3/31/23 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 |  |  |
| B | 150 | 150 |  |
| C | 200 | 200 | 200 |

In python I have created a date range with frequency 'M'. The idea I am trying to accomplish is if the date is less than the Maturity date, repeat balance.

Answer (score 0):

[`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html):

```
(df.pivot(index='Item', columns='Maturity', values='Balance')
   .sort_index(axis=1, key=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, dayfirst=False))
   .bfill(axis=1)
)
```

*NB. [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) using conversion [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to ensure the correct order of the columns.*

Output:

```
Maturity  1/31/23  2/28/23  3/31/23
Item                               
A           100.0      NaN      NaN
B           150.0    150.0      NaN
C           200.0    200.0    200.0
```